# Applying node.js server to a web server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, raspberry-pi, p5.js

I am trying to learn how to use Node.js and web sockets to create simple multi-user interactive javascript programs. I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjULmG8fqc8) tutorial series by Daniel Shiffman to create [this](https://github.com/CodingTrain/Rainbow-Code/tree/master/Node/sockets) example project. My next step would be to upload it, using WinSCP, to my RaspberryPi apache2 web server, but I haven't found a way to edit the code in a way to allow for that to work, and furthermore, I do not know what piece of the programs to execute to make it function properly.

Any assistance would be great. The extent of my Node / Socket.io knowledge comes entirely from the video series mentioned above, so you can assume I know almost nothing else.

Comment: You have fully functional server and you can run it without need anything else just nodejs. so upload it to you raspberry and `node server.js` and everything is good :)

Comment: could you explain that further, I get what your saying, but I don't understand how to apply it.@ParhamAlvani

Answer (score 2):

Apache is a web server and it serves your file and send them to client for you, so when you have some client side things like html site with some css, javascript and images you can use apache to send them to client for you.

In node.js you can create this web server simply by following code and express library:

```
// Create the app
var app = express();

// Set up the server
var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('http server is ready')
});
```

as you created in your code too. by this web server you can host your files and do many more things like setup socket.io server and ... because you write web server yourself. with following code you serve static files in public directory (html, css, javascript and images ...):

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

after you finishing this process you can run it simply by:

```
npm install
node server.js
```

if you want you can run you code inside docker by creating Dockerfile and ...

About your question, you must move all your project files into raspberry and at the end you have following directory tree in somewhere in raspberry:

```
|- server.js
|- package.json
\ public
```

at this directory run above commands and your server will be up and running and you can access to it by `http://raspberry_ip:3000`.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to respond, but I still do not understand what I am supposed to do. My two main questions are 1) where to I type the commands 'npm install' and 'node server.js'. 2) What file do I open in the url to access the page?

Comment: I improve my answer, can I explain what you need ?

Comment: You type them either in a terminal on the pi or by ssh'ing to the pi. The url will be the ip of your pi, followed by ":3000"

Comment: Very helpful answer, but I when I use the two command I asked about earlier the pi says that the command is not found!?

Comment: you must move the files and type commands in rpi terminal, after these are setup you can access them on `127.0.0.1:300` in rpi and `rpi_ip:3000` from all computer in a local network with rpi

Comment: you must install nodejs in rpi, see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Comment: I installed node.js on the pi and got the server to run, but I still can't find how to access it through a url (I have a domain provided by no-ip.com). Is there anywhere in the code where I have to specify the path to the server, or index.html in the code?

Comment: is your server running ? what do you see on terminal after `node server.js` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147116/discussion-between-parham-alvani-and-zachary-elkins).